# Escaping of > char in havingRaw to &gt;

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel Framework 8.37.0
PHP 8.0.3

```php
public function scopePending($query) {
    $query->join('workshops', 'workshops.event_id', '=', 'events.id')
        ->groupBy('events.id')
        ->havingRaw('min(workshops.start) > NOW()');
}
```

Returns the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'laravel8testapp.events.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `events`.* from `events` inner join `workshops` on `workshops`.`event_id` = `events`.`id` group by `events`.`id` having min(workshops.start) &gt; NOW()) in file /var/www/laravel8testapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 678
```

It somehow escapes the `>` with `&gt;` in a raw expression.
In normal where queries `>` works as expected.
If I run the query manually (with `&gt;` replaced with `>`) it works as expected

Do you guys have any ideas?
Maybe its just some issue on my side or is it a reproducible bug?

Best regards

Comment: I'd think the actual error is `'laravel8testapp.events.name' isn't in GROUP BY ...`. It's probably just the *error message* being HTML escaped, not the query.

Comment: I test that further but if I copy & paste the query from the error message to the console it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as the Exception mentions, my bad:

`'laravel8testapp.events.name' isn't in GROUP BY``

Using
`SET SQL_MODE=''`solves the issue though that I would not recommend.